# Function to remove newline has no effect?

Tags: c

I have written a function to wrap GNU getline() and remove the trailing newline, but for some reason it has no effect. Am I doing something wrong?

```
ssize_t readline(char **lineptr, FILE *stream)
{
  size_t len = 0;  // Size of the buffer, ignored.

  ssize_t chars = getline(lineptr, &len, stream);

  if((*lineptr)[chars] == '\n') {
    (*lineptr)[chars] = '\0';
    --chars;
  }

  return chars;
}
```

It compiles and links without problems, but the newline is not replaced with a null-terminator. I've verified the if() statement is running. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Just used this for stripping that newline, 
g_strchomp(line)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`getline` returns the number of characters read. So you have to use `chars-1` rather than `char`.

```
if ((*lineptr)[chars - 1] == '\n') 
  {
      (*lineptr)[chars - 1] = '\0';
      --chars;
  }
```

> **man getline (3)**
>
> On success, `getline()` and `getdelim()` return the number of characters read, including the > delimiter character, but not
>   including the terminating null byte. This value can be used to handle
>   embedded null bytes in the line read.

Answer (score 4):

You want to check and replace the last character, not the one **after** it.

```
if ((*lineptr)[chars - 1] == '\n') {
    (*lineptr)[chars - 1] = '\0';
}
```

(`getline()` returns the number of characters read, just as `strlen()` returns the length of a string, **excluding** the terminating 0 character.)