# Problem with removing the "\n" from a string read in with getline()

Tags: c, string, pointers, io, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Hello I am very new to the C programming language and I am writing my first program in C. I want to remove the "\n" from the end of a line read in with getline() and replace it with "\0". I tried it with the code that is in the if-statement, the first expression in my while loop but I am not getting the behaviour I intended.
I tried the solution suggested here [Function to remove newline has no effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000047/function-to-remove-newline-has-no-effect/13000096) but it did not work for my case, and I don't understand why, I assume I am making a mistake with the pointers but I can not figure out what it is. What exactly am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

```
void foo(FILE *input, FILE *output) {
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t length = 0;
    ssize_t chars_read;

    while ((chars_read= getline(&line, &length, input)) != -1) {
        if (line[chars_read-1] == '\n') {
            line[chars_read-1] = '\0';
            chars_read = chars_read - 1;
        }
        char *line_rev = malloc(sizeof(char)*chars_read);
        bar(line, line_rev, chars_read);
        if (strcmp(line, line_rev) == 0) {
            ...
        } else {
            ...
        }
        free(line_rev);
    }

    free(line);
}
```

Update: Thanks for all the helpful answers! For future visitors: Be careful when working on WSL, new lines might be '\n' or '\r' depending on the OS you are working on. For details check Ted's answer ;).

Comment: Hint: make it *two* functions. Divide&conquer. [ &test ...]

Comment: "I am not getting the behavior I intended", meaning what? Please show an example of what you see and what you'd expect instead.

Comment: You have a length variable that is unused, and you haven't defined len anywhere (its passed into getline).

Comment: Is this on Linux / MacOS, or on Windows? On Windows, newlines can also use `"\r\n"` so maybe there's an `'\r'` left?

Comment: @LukeNelson that was a typo it is fixed now i use the length variable in the getline() funciton.

Comment: @Bart I am on Windows using WSL (Ubuntu)

Comment: `line[strcspn(line, "\r\n")] = 0;` is one nice approach if you don't know the number of chars read, btw. But you do in this case so there are better ways. What you're doing looks fine.

Comment: @Shawn Well that worked thank you, gonna look into what the function does in detail.

Comment: The line `char *line_rev = malloc(sizeof(char)*chars_read);` is dubious; you have not allocated space for the null that will need to be added to the end of the string.  You need to allocation `chars_read + 1` bytes.  Multiplying by `sizeof(char)` is the same as multiplying by `1` and is not particularly helpful.

Comment: I suspect @Bart is on to something and carriage returns from a Windows style file are messing you up (hence including it in the `strcspn()` characters). Common issue with WSL environments.

Comment: @Shawn yes I think that is the case indeed since I tried Ted Lyngmo 's code snipped without the "special care for windows line endings" part and it did not work ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is simply to put a `\0` where the `\n` is.

It could look like this;

```
char *line = NULL;
size_t length = 0;
ssize_t chars_read;
// ...

    if(chars_read > 0 && line[chars_read-1] == '\n') {
        line[chars_read-1] = '\0';
        // special care for windows line endings:
        if(chars_read > 1 && line[char_read-2] == '\r') line[chars_read-2] = '\0';
    }
```

Comment: @TedLyngmo I tried your approach too but sadly I had the same result as with my initial if statement, the "\n" did not get replaced.

Comment: @CoffeeKid: How did you establish that the newline was not deleted?  I'd use something like `printf("[[%s]]\n", line);` to see — if the `]]` appears on a new line, there is a newline in the data; if not, it was removed.  If the `]]` appears at the start of the line with the rest of the data, there is a carriage return `'\r'` in the data.

Comment: @CoffeeKid I suggest that you check what `line` actually contains. Print out _all_ its contents.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I did that by writing the contents to an output file and the string still contained a newline.

Comment: @CoffeeKid If it did, it magically was not at the end of the string returned by `getline`. Try this after my `if(...) { .. }`: `for(char* ch = line; *ch != '\0'; ++ch); printf("%d\n", *ch);` - What does that show?

Comment: 97
98
99
99
98
97 is the output for it with the input "abccba" with a newline at the end.

Comment: @CoffeeKid ... there is no newline at the end there. `97` is `a`.

Comment: By the way I tried your code snipped again and it worked now, might have been a mistake on my part.

Comment: @CoffeeKid: that newline came from somewhere else — the code would print `10` for the newline if it was present.

Comment: @TedLyngmo by the way by "with a newline at the end" i meant the input, not the output. So yes indeed it got removed ;) thanks a lot!

Comment: @TedLyngmo [There are buggy `getline()` implementations out there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46313018/getline-returns-1-eof-not-set-errno-not-set-when-given-very-large-input).  `chars_read != -1` would be better as `chars_read > 0`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle `chars_read > 0` will be `true` if `getline` returns `(size_t)-1` so that's not the proper test alone. It would have to be `chars_read != -1 && chars_read > 0` to work. I think it's better not to taint the answer with things dealing with buggy implementations. I hope the buggy implementations have gotten bugfixed by now.

Comment: @TedLyngmo [The POSIX documentation says `getline()` returns `ssize_t`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html):  "`ssize_t getline(char **restrict lineptr, size_t *restrict n, FILE *restrict stream);`" so the `-1` check *should* be redundant.  But as `getline()` isn't standard C, perhaps you have a different implementation in mind?  Or there's another bug out there...

Comment: @AndrewHenle You are correct! Jeez, I read `size_t` not `ssize_t` :-) Thanks, fixing answer.

Comment: It's too early in the morning. :-)

Comment: @AndrewHenle :-) I wrote this yesterday so I can't blame the morning :-D

Answer (score 0):

To replace a potential `'\n'` in a *string* with a `'\0'`:

```
 line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = '\0';
```

To utilizing the prior length `chars_read`:

```
 if (chars_read > 0 && line[chars_read - 1] == '\n') {
   line[--chars_read] = '\0';
 }
```

---

`malloc()` is 1 too short for OP's need.

```
    // char *line_rev = malloc(sizeof(char)*chars_read);
    char *line_rev = malloc(sizeof(char)*(chars_read + 1));
    bar(line, line_rev, chars_read);
    if (strcmp(line, line_rev) == 0) {
```

Comment: Really not needed with `getline()` which reports how many characters it read, including the newline but not the trailing null, into the array it is working with.

Comment: I am very curious since @Shawn suggested a very similar answer to yours but with = 0 instead of = '\0' and it worked just fine too (just like your suggestion).  Could you elaborate whats the difference, and why both approaches work?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Agree'd ,  Of course the line may lack a final `'\n'` on end-of-file.

Comment: @CoffeeKid `0`, `'\0'`, `00`, `0.0` and others all are a _zero_.  Much is a style difference.

Comment: One major difference between `0.0` and the other alternatives is the type — the others are all integers, but `0.0` is a `double` value.

Comment: @Reinstate Monia Oh right because chars are basically ints in C?

Comment: @CoffeeKid I prefer to use `'\0'` when assigning to a `char`, a '0' to an integer type and 0.0 to a FP type.

Comment: @CoffeeKid `char` is an _integer_ type, yet `0`, `'\0'`, `00` are all type `int`.

Comment: If you're worried about files without trailing newlines, you can check before you zap the newline.  If you're worried about CRLF line endings, you can check for the CR (`'\r'`) after you zap the NL (LF — `'\n'`).  Remember to check for empty lines with just a newline — don't go accessing space before the start of `line`.  That may make it sensible to use the `strcspn()` variation after all — but it depends on the level of paranoia you wish to acknowledge.

Comment: Can `getline()` ever return 0?

Comment: @Shawn Recall `getline()` is not a standard C library function, so depending on the implementation, who knows?  Common linux versions do not return 0 - yet this post not tagged as such.  Recall that the first (or later) character read could pathologically be a _null character_, such than `strlen(line) != chars_read`.

Comment: @Shawn: Interesting question – my understanding is that the answer is "No".  The POSIX specification for [`getline()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) says: _Upon successful completion, … getline() … shall return the number of bytes written into the buffer, including the delimiter character if one was encountered before EOF, but excluding the terminating NUL character. If the [EOF] indicator … is set, or if no characters were read and the stream is at [EOF], the [EOF] indicator for the stream shall be set and the function shall return -1._ […continued…]

Comment: […continuation…] _If an error occurs, the error indicator for the stream shall be set, and the function shall return -1 and set errno to indicate the error._. That does not leave a way for `0` to be a valid return.  If there was no data, then it returns `-1` (not `EOF` — though they are usually the same value); if there was any data, it returns the number of bytes read, which must be at least `1`.

Comment: I thought it would be obvious I'm talking about the POSIX function.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That's my understanding too. Though checking to see if the length is 1 or more is a harmless bit of redundancy.